# Errors "No such file or directory" ,"command not found" seen while running my shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

The contents of my script

```
`sqlline.py tpxxx.entexxx.org <<END

!outputformat csv

!record /ap_data/DD3/Rawf/Raw_f_$1_$2.csv

select column1,column2,column3,column4 from DD3_vxxv_$1.DD3_vv_RAW_DATA where v_id=$3 and period=$4;

!record

!quit

END;`

`sed -i '1d;$d' /ap_data/DD3/Rawf/Raw_f_$1_$2.csv;

sed -i "s/'//g" /ap_data/DD3/Rawf/Raw_f_$1_$2.csv;

cd /ap_data/D2O/RawDownload/

zip Raw_f_$1_$2.zip Raw_f_$1_$2.csv;

scp Raw_f_$1_$2.zip txxx@daxxxx.entexxx.org:/opt/cdar/common/D2O/TabUpload/;

rm Raw_f_$1_$2.csv Raw_f_$1_$2.zip;`
```

On executing the script:

```
./rawfile.sh: line 7: 0/?: No such file or directory
./rawfile.sh: line 13: adding:: command not found
```

The script gives correct output. But still shows the errors "No such file or directory", "command not found"

My file permission is:   -rwxrwxrwx

Comment: what is "Avoide" ?  this question needs more information or close it.

Comment: error is within your script , not in file permissions.

Comment: What are lines 7 and 13 of the script?

Comment: 7th line: END;`

13th line:  rm Raw_Data_$1_$2.csv Raw_Data_$1_$2.zip;`

Answer (score 1):

Your script has backquotes around two main executable sections.

Backquotes cause the content within to be executed in a subshell and substituted back into your script.  This means that in your case, your script is executing TWO commands.  One of them is the output of the first backquoted expression, and the other is the output of the second backquoted expression.

For example:

```
$ `echo hello`
bash: hello: command not found
$ `echo echo hello`
hello
```

What's happening here is that the first `echo` command generates output which is substituted into your command line, making the command line evaluated by the shell simply "hello" .. which is not a command. The second command line prints "echo hello", which is a valid command line and evaluates to something that prints "hello".

Remove the backquotes from around your two main statements, and just execute the commands directly.

```
#!/bin/sh

sqlline.py tpxxx.entexxx.org <<END
!outputformat csv
!record /ap_data/DD3/Rawf/Raw_f_$1_$2.csv
select column1,column2,column3,column4 from DD3_vxxv_$1.DD3_vv_RAW_DATA where v_id=$3 and period=$4;
!record
!quit
END

sed -i '1d;$d' /ap_data/DD3/Rawf/Raw_f_$1_$2.csv
sed -i "s/'//g" /ap_data/DD3/Rawf/Raw_f_$1_$2.csv
cd /ap_data/D2O/RawDownload/
zip Raw_f_$1_$2.zip Raw_f_$1_$2.csv
scp Raw_f_$1_$2.zip txxx@daxxxx.entexxx.org:/opt/cdar/common/D2O/TabUpload/
rm Raw_f_$1_$2.csv Raw_f_$1_$2.zip
```